# UIDocumentMenuViewController have wrong frame listView

Tags: objective-c, ios12, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, uidocumentmenuviewcontroller

Good day to all. I support the old version of the application written on Objective C . I want to implement a functional - File Browser(File Provider). But using UIDocumentMenuViewController or UIDocumentPickerViewController i have problem with display my files. Help me how you implement the file provider in your applications on  Objective C.Problem - Content is cropped at the bottom of the screen . Thx
[image: Content is cropped at the bottom of the screen]